# How can I use an owl dataset anyOntology.owl for generating grails domain classes

Tags: grails, owl, protege

I'm an owl/protege newbe with some grails experience.

I would like to transform my protege ontology file anyOntology.owl to grails domain classes. In the next step I would use grails generate-all command to obtain the respective controllers and views to obtain the executable model with CRUD functionality, which would be my executable ontology.

Is there already something like a protege-export or a grails-import as a plugin, or is someone already planning/working on such a feature?

Peter

Answer (score 1):

in the meantime I developed a 0.1 Version for the above Problem and promoted it to
https://github.com/pstrotmann/ontology/tree/HEAD/owlToOO
It is a grails Application, that transforms an xxxx.owl file to grails Domain classes that can be transformed to a grails application by using the generate_all feature of grails thus obtaining a CRUD functionality. 
In addition a graphViz input is generated from the xxxx.owl file that can be transformed by graphViz to an UML-Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

in addition there is runnable version of owlToOO that can be accessed via
http://partnerontology.strotmann.org
with a generated Partner application